# PCIe - Accessing Peer Endpoint's Memory Space

Tags: memory, pci-express, memory-management, peer-to-peer

I have two PCIe endpoints connected to two root ports on the same host machine and I am trying to access the memory space allocated for the other endpoint from the first endpoint by sending a 32-bit Memory Read TLP. But I get an ***Unsupported Request*** error in the Completion Status. The *MemRd* is being sent to the *BAR0* Address assigned to the endpoint. I also tried sending *MemRd* to the same endpoint's *BAR0* but that fails as well.

[image: Unsupported Request Error]

I am able to access the same memory region using [RWEverything](https://rweverything.com/)

[image: RWEverything Access]

Quite possible I am doing something silly.

Comment: Increase your idle time. Successful attempt idle time is 5x longer then the unsuccessful attempt

Comment: I don't have any control on the Idle time. It is just the time between end of current packet and the beginning of next.